# Microsoft Report Viewer Processing Object

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Do i need to have Microsoft Report Viewer as part of my published program?  I had created a program that was able to install on other computers but with my latest version there was an error upon install that Microsoft Report Viewer object 11 was not installed.  I did not add a report viewer to my project at all and i am wondering if i can simply delete the Report Viewer from my resources??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question.  Under my Properties, References, i was able to remove all of the Unused References which included the Report Viewer.  Somewhere i must have added something that added the report viewer but i never used it so the program is now able to load.